# Div Tag/Background Not Centering

Tags: html, mobile, coding-style, alignment

I'm in the early stages of building a mobile version of our website, and I'm already having an issue with a div tag & background not centering.  The stylesheet code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
BODY{margin-left: 0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px; background-color:#fff;FONT-SIZE:12px;COLOR:#000000;FONT-FAMILY:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
header {
        display:block;text-align:center;width:100%;height:6.5em;
}

.topHeader {display:block; width:100%;  height:5.4em;}
#acdlogo {
    float:left;text-align:left; overflow:hidden; display:inline;
}

#acdHeadLinks {
    float:right;text-align:right;margin-top:5px;
}

.clearAll { clear:both; font-size:0; padding:0; margin:0; }

.search-bg {  
    text-align:center;width:85%;background-color:#265e99;
    height:45px;z-index:1000; border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Here is the code that appears after the stylesheet code:

```
<body>
<div>
  <header>
    <div class="topHeader" align="center">
            <div id="acdlogo">
            <a href="http://www.test.com/" title="Test"><img src="images/logo.gif" border="0" alt="Alt Text"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="acdHeadLinks">
                <a href="tel:8005551212"><img src="images/mcontact.png" border="0"></a><br>
                <a href="">Directions</a> <a href="">My Account</a> <a href="">My Cart</a>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div align="center" class="search-bg" id="searchgcs">
        hello world
    </div>

   </header>
</div>
</body></html>
```

The problem is that the blue background is supposed to hold the search engine form, but it's aligning left not center, and I don't know what I need to do to center it.  I'm trying real hard not to have to use tables.  Anybody can help me figure this out?  Thanks!

UPDATE: Alright I have a new error.  I'm trying to center an image using div tags and I'm not getting anywhere, even with the answer below.  I've even stripped down the code to only attempt to center the image and no go.  The image is always aligned left inside the div tag and I want it centered.   Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#mainImage {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
img.curMainImage {
    max-height:240px;
    max-width:240px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainImage"><img class="curMainImage" src="Image Here" border="0" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: You could try margin:auto, although that will not have any affect if your width is set to 100%. Edit: Also, have you tried the ugly, yet possibly effective <center> html tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `.search-bg`  - http://jsfiddle.net/7djxY/1/

```
.search-bg {       
    text-align:center;
    width:85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#265e99;     
    height:45px;
    z-index:1000;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

**Update:** the `margin: 0 auto;` is used to set the top and bottom margins to 0, and the left-right margins to auto. In that case the browser will automatically detect the available side margin space and distribute it equally to the left and right. And with the same margins both sides the element becomes centered.

Comment: That worked!  And could you explain why the addition of "margin: 0 auto;" fixed the issue for future knowledge?

Comment: Awesome!  I'm still more or less new to this stuff, so any help like this is greatly appreciated!  Thanks man!